# Haskell: Why was `par` defined the way it was?

Tags: multithreading, haskell, parallel-processing, par

`par` is declared as:

```
par  :: a -> b -> b
```

Notice, that argument one is thrown away. In order to use par you need to play tricks like using the same expression multiple times.

If its purpose is to execute a and b in parallel, why wasn't it defined like this?:

```
par  :: (a, b) -> (a, b)
```

Taking a tuple of (unevaluated) expressions and returning the same expressions - while they are potentially being materialized on background threads.

It seems the latter model is simpler than the former. Why was the design chosen that way?

Comment: I find your version more difficult to think about.  The pair you pass to par might be unevaluated.  Who evaluates it and when?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the former, you can easily spark more than two computations,

```
c1 `par` c2 `par` c3 `par` c4 `pseq` something c1 c2 c3 c4
```

which would be rather cumbersome in the latter.

Comment: The latter could be overloaded for up to 8 args and have a list version, too.

Comment: Notice, that argument one is thrown away which means only c4 from your example will survive (without further tricks).

Comment: How would you overload it? `class par a where` and instances for up to 8-tuples? Ugh.

Comment: The trick is that you _use_ the results of the sparked computations in the final value, which gets a `pseq` too.

Comment: @usr : haskell 'par' and 'pseq' features are tightly coupled to the evaluation model. You should have a look at the "lazy evaluation with sharing" model, as well as the garbage collection model.

Comment: So I guess you could say that the Haskell compiler needs to recognize that the expression c1 is used multiple times and allocate a single "lazy evaluation slot" for both usages? If it didn't allocate one slot only, one copy would be calculated in parallel but thrown away.

Answer (score 7):

The tupled version you suggest can be found as parTuple2 in Control.Parallel.Strategies, with the type:

```
evalTuple2 :: Strategy a -> Strategy b -> Strategy (a, b)
```

As for why *par* was designed that way, *par* is 'higher level', as chapter 24 of [Real World Haskell](http://book.realworldhaskell.org/read/concurrent-and-multicore-programming.html) discusses, where they parallelize a quicksort:

> These changes to our code are remarkable for all the things we have
>     not needed to say.
>
> - How many cores to use.
> - What threads do to communicate with each other.
> - How to divide up work among the available cores.
> - Which data are shared between threads, and which are private.
> - How to determine when all the participants are finished.

In [A Monad for Deterministic Parallelism](http://community.haskell.org/~simonmar/papers/monad-par.pdf), Marlow, Newton, and Peyton Jones write:

> The par operator is an attractive language design because it
>   capitalises on the overlap between lazy evaluation and futures.
>   To implement lazy evaluation we must have a representation for
>   expressions which are not yet evaluated but whose value may
>   later be demanded; and similarly a future is a computation whose
>   value is being evaluated in parallel and which we may wait for.
>   Hence, par was conceived as a mechanism for annotating a lazy
>   computation as being potentially proﬁtable to evaluate in parallel,
>   in effect turning a lazy computation into a future